# Difference between matrix.setValues(float []values) and setting matrix.setScale(),setSkew(),setTranslate() separately,why they act differently?

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, android-imageview

```
float values[] = new float[]{sx,skx,tx,
                         sky,sy,ty,
                          0,0,1}
matrix.setValues(values);
```

or

```
matrix.setScale(sx,sy);
matrix.setSkew(skx,sky);
matrix.setTranslate(tx,ty);
```

they act differently, matrix.setValues() give the exact result,while setting the same values they work differently,
I need to use 2_nd approach and have the right result.
How it could be done?

or using the approach setValues() for bitmap ,while I need to use set... methods for canvas to skew textview and the results are different

Comment: setTranslate sets the whole Matrix resetting the rotate and scale part,  the same applies to setScale and setRotate

Comment: What could I do,if I need to translate ,scale and skew canvas for transforming text?

Comment: use post*/pre* methods

Comment: thanks ,it possible for matrix but what i need to do for scaling,skewing translating text?. for setting these values canvas have only setScale(),setSkew() setTranlate() methods

Comment: what do you mean?  I dont understand your point

Comment: I use matrix.setValues() and use for drawBitmap,while I need to transform text with same values,and I use set methods and it doesn't give the appropriate positions for text.
matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setValues(matrixValues);
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBmp, matrix, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(matrixValues[4],matrixValues[5]);
canvas.scale(matrixValues[0],matrixValues[1]);
canvas.skew(matrixValues[3],matrixValues[2]);
canvas.drawText("HI HI HI HI", 30, 200, paint);
canvas.restore();

Comment: Dont use Matrix.setValues, use pre/post methods,  also use Canvas.concat

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help ,it's not the first time that you save my day.Thanks.